# No Source Available during Minidump Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files, minidump

I am currently stuck with some debugging issues... hope you guys can help me out! I have developed a software and have given it out to some people.

Now if the programm crashes, which has happened a couple of times, the program writes a minidump file and sends it to me.

I have opened this minidump file in VS2012 and tried to debug it with the source code. I have linked the pdb files in the properties page: **Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Symbol file locations**. As far as I can judge it, the pdb files are found and are used in VS.

However, my source files are not linked. There is always the page - No Source Available - displayed. I tried several advices given in stackoverflow, the microsoft support page and other google results. The basic thing everybody said is to link the source files in **Solution RightClick -> Properties -> Debug Source Files** by adding the source file paths. I added nearly every possible path but it still didnt work. I even opened the minidump file in my developing solution in which all source files are build and located and tried to debug in that solution -> Unfortunately no success.

Has anyone from you encountered this problem? Do you know a way to look at the errors in the source codes?

Comment: You need to enable Microsoft Symbol Server in the debugger. You need to use the same .pdb files that was produced when the program was built. You cannot just rebuild the same source and use .pdb files from this build. Add .pdb files path to the debugger, in the same dialog where Microsoft Symbol Server is defined.

Comment: If the program crashes within Microsoft written code then, commonly, source code will not be available. Check the call stack to see whether your code is named higher up the call stack.

Comment: While debugging the mini-dump, select Debug/Windows/Modules.  The window that displays will show the status of all of the files that are currently loaded.  If any say "no matching binary", you have a mismatch between what is currently loaded and the binaries that are producing the dump files.